# Librosa throws ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, audio, speech, valueerror, librosa

> x_val, s_rate = librosa.load(file_name, sr=sampling_rate)
>
> File "/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 140, in
>   load
>       y = sf_desc.read(frames=frame_duration, dtype=dtype, always_2d=False).T
>
> File "/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py",
>   line 862, in read
>       frames = self._check_frames(frames, fill_value)
>
> File "/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1270, in _check_frames
>
> ```
> raise ValueError("frames must be specified for non-seekable files") ValueError: frames must be specified for non-seekable files
> ```

I am getting the above error when I try to load a .wav file using Librosa. I have ffmpeg installed and .mp3 files are loading fine without any issues. I couldn't understand what this error meant. Any explanation of the error or any solution to solve the issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the version of `libsndfile`?

Comment: try with a different files? make sure to try both mono and stereo .wav files so you can narrow the cause down.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski: How can I do that? I was trying to find a way to check the version but so far I couldn't find anything that's useful to find the version on Linux.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski: Based on information online, I just checked usr/share/doc directory and there is a folder that says libsndfile1 there. So, I guess the verion is 1.

Comment: @SuperKogito: Thank you for your reply, will try to see if at least one among mono or stereo works well.

Comment: Run `ldconfig -v | grep libraryname`. For instance, I have `libsndfile.so.1.0.28`.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski: Thanks for your reply, it returned: `libsndfile.so.1 -> libsndfile.so.1.0.28`

Comment: hey, I have same error, did you solve it?

Comment: It's been a long time and I don't remember how I solved it, but I think it was either due to improper ffmpeg installation/permissions on Windows or due to a corrupt file, but I am leaning more to the former. Make sure that your ffmpeg installation is working well.

Answer (score 0):

check the bit rate of your file. some of my wave file had 71kbps and I would get the same error. I converted them to 256kbps, 16kHZ and it worked.
I'm using librosa 0.9.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).