# librosa load --> ValueError("frames must be specified for non-seekable files")

Tags: python, librosa

My python version is 3.6, librosa version is 0.7.0

I read wav file using librosa library.
`y,fs = librosa.load("file1.wav")`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda_env/personal/susan/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 138, in load
    y = sf_desc.read(frames=frame_duration, dtype=dtype, always_2d=False).T
  File "/anaconda_env/personal/susan/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 860, in read
    frames = self._check_frames(frames, fill_value)
  File "/anaconda_env/personal/susan/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1268, in _check_frames
    raise ValueError("frames must be specified for non-seekable files")
ValueError: frames must be specified for non-seekable files
```

May I know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496724/librosa-throws-valueerror

Comment: I already checked that issue. The problem was not solved in that link.

Comment: is it working properly for other file types?

Comment: No. It does not work .
When I checked the libsndfile with this command ```ldconfig -v | grep libraryname```, I got 
```/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

        libsndfile.so.1 -> libsndfile.so.1.0.26
        libsndfile.so.1 -> libsndfile.so.1.0.25
```

Comment: May I know does it mean I need libsndfile 1.0.25? 
I already tried replacing libsndfile1 with libsndfile 1.0.25 in the directory /usr/share/doc/ because in the directory /usr/share/doc/, I have libsndfile1
I got the same frame issue.

Comment: One thing is I can read the same wav file in the window via librosa. I got no issue in the window. However when I tried in the linux, I got the issue of ```ValueError: frames must be specified for non-seekable files```. I don't think the wav file is a problem.